# Meteor build TypeError: module.import is not a function

Tags: meteor

In the last couple of days I have been having trouble building. I moved to Meteor 1.4.2, and I'm not sure if that is the problem. I tried going back to Meteor 1.4.1.3 but the problem is still there

The error I am getting is

```
W20161108-11:17:17.631(11)? (STDERR) /Users/mikkel/senecto/memberapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:333
W20161108-11:17:17.632(11)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20161108-11:17:17.632(11)? (STDERR)    ^
W20161108-11:17:17.632(11)? (STDERR)
W20161108-11:17:17.632(11)? (STDERR) TypeError: module.import is not a function
W20161108-11:17:17.633(11)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.webapp.webapp_server.js (/Users/mikkel/senecto/memberapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/webapp.js:33:26)
W20161108-11:17:17.633(11)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/packages/modules-runtime.js:171:1)
W20161108-11:17:17.633(11)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/packages/modules-runtime.js:96:1)
W20161108-11:17:17.633(11)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mikkel/senecto/memberapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/webapp.js:842:1
W20161108-11:17:17.633(11)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mikkel/senecto/memberapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/webapp.js:855:3
W20161108-11:17:17.633(11)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mikkel/senecto/memberapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:292:10
W20161108-11:17:17.633(11)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20161108-11:17:17.634(11)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/mikkel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_3.89kw9a++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20161108-11:17:17.634(11)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mikkel/senecto/memberapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
=> Exited with code: 1
```

I don't understand what is wrong, meteor reset has no effect, not does removing the build directory.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you tried removing `~/.meteor`? Also, is there a smallest set of code you can use to reproduce this problem and potentially share?

Comment: @ChristianFritz that's a good idea to remove ~/.meteor, as I have 2 Macs that don't have the problem, and one that does. I know that reverting to 1.4.1.3 does make it go away

Comment: Looks like you are a winner :) Make an answer and I'll mark it as correct, and you can get the bonus. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, deleting `~/.meteor` resolves this issue. When this directory is deleted, Meteor will reinstall all packages, incl. core packages.

Comment: You are talking about .meteor in my app or at my home dicrectory?

How can this be a solution? It will remove my settings? And that for destroy my project if you are talking about .meteor in my project?

Comment: As the `~` indicates, this is the `.meteor` folder in your home directory. And no, there are no settings or anything stored there. It's just a cache.